# How do I use a database-based mailing list?

Tags: php, database, email, mailing-list

I'm thinking of adding a mailing list to my webpage, where a user submits their email address, which is added to a table in a database on my server. After I set up all the PHP, how will I be able to actually send a newsletter to all the contacts?

Comment: Must've slipped my mind; thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, your best bet is to look at any number of mailing list tools (including free PHP applications like PHPList) to do this.  There is actually a lot of things you need to consider in order to implement a mailing list tool - including things like bounce processing, user opt-out, etc.

There really is no sense in reinventing the wheel.

Comment: +1 for "no sense in reinventing the wheel".